# Is a question off topic when asked by professionals or corporations?

Tags: discussion, scope, moderation

There have been questions closed because they were asked by people representing companies (e.g. [this question was debated](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/48903/2196)). Should be person asking the question impact whether the question is on or off topic, or should the decision be strictly based on the topic of the question itself?

Answer (score 9):

My own opinion is that decisions to close a question should be based on only the question and not the person asking it. In the above linked question, it was asking about gaps in floor boards. Answers to this question are useful to other homeowners experiencing the same problem and so the question should be considered on topic.

Comment: Are there limits, and how are they determined?

Comment: The limits for me are based on [the help center topic](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If a corporation asks a question that would be out of scope even if an individual asked it, then it's off topic.

Comment: Or if the corporation is using the question as a means of promoting its own goods or services.